# jquery validate date of birth in multiple text fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, jquery-validate

I've been searching for a definite way to validate the date of birth when it's split in three different text fields. SO far I have a single input field that handles that correctly, but I can't change the html code.SO I still need this to comply with the 3 text-field group.I read that using an hidden input field that validates the values entered in the three fields for date of birth can be a solution. Can anyone give me hand with this.

This is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b8fubr5u/1/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.validator.addMethod("dob", function (value, element) {
        var result = true;
        var ageMin = 18;
        var ageMax = 85;

        //is the date valid?
        //is it within the allowed range
        var myDate = value.split("/");
        var subDay = myDate[0];
        var subMonth = myDate[1] - 1;
        var subYear = myDate[2];
        var subDate = new Date(subYear, subMonth, subDay);
        // this will "correct" any out of range input
        var calcDay = subDate.getDate();
        var calcMonth = subDate.getMonth();
        var calcYear = subDate.getFullYear();
        // this checks to see if any of the submitted input was out of range
        // comment this out to ignore the discrepancy if you want to set a "corrected" value below
        if (calcDay != subDay || calcMonth != subMonth || calcYear != subYear) {
            $.validator.messages.dob = "Invalid date";
            result = false;
        }

        if (result) {
            var currDate = new Date();
            var currYear = currDate.getFullYear();
            var currMonth = currDate.getMonth();
            var currDay = currDate.getDate();

            var age = currYear - subYear;

            if (subMonth > currMonth) {
                age = age - 1; // next birthday not yet reached
            } else if (subMonth == currMonth && currDay < subDay) {
                age = age - 1;
            }

            if (ageMin != undefined) {
                if (age < ageMin) {
                    $.validator.messages.dob = "Min 18 years old";
                    result = false;
                }
            }

            if (ageMax != undefined) {
                if (age > ageMax) {
                    $.validator.messages.dob = "Invalid date";
                    result = false;
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    },
        "Please enter a date in the format DD/MM/YYYY");

    $("#form").validate({
        rules: {
            dateBirth: {
                required: true,
                dob: true
            },
            month: {
                required: true,
                dob: true
            },
            dobDay: {
                required: true,
                range: [1, 31]
            },
            dobMonth: {
                required: true,
                range: [1, 12]
            },
            dobYear: {
                required: true
            }
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
$(".bday").on('keyup',function(){
    var bday = $('[name="dobDay"]').val()+"/"+$('[name="dobMonth"]').val()+"/"+$('[name="dobYear"]').val();
    $("#dateBirth").val(bday );
});
```

This is the fiddle working: http://jsfiddle.net/b8fubr5u/8/